# Is there any python function to call Mac OS frameworks like ctypes wilndll does?

Tags: python, dll, frameworks, ctypes

Is there any python function to call Mac OS frameworks like ctypes wilndll does?

I am trying to build botu win and mac OS app, since the H/W manufacturer released both .dll and .framework with almost same structure and functions.
Is there any equivalent of ctypes in OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctypes is a foreign function library for Python. It provides C compatible data types, and allows calling functions in DLLs or shared libraries. It can be used to wrap these libraries in pure Python.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html

Comment: I hope my answer is useful